# Why Mishna Berurah chooses chesronaM with a M in borei nefashos?

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, nusach-ashkenaz, mishnah-berurah

Mishna Berurah 202:3 quotes the nusach of borei nefashos as "Boreh Nefashos Rabos VeChesronaM" with a M in opposition to the common version vechesronaN with a N.

As "vechesronan" is referring to "nefashos" and "nefashos" is feminine genre to me N version is the correct one according to hebrew grammar.

Could someone explain this mishna berurah strange position and the arguments for the M for vechesronaM ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Aruch HaShulchan [O.C. 207](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%96):2 defends and prefers the Mishna Brurah's nusach. The argument for the Mem is that in several places in the Torah we find Nefesh followed by a masculine verb, because when referring to the whole person, of which the Nefesh is a part, then the masculine should be used. Only when refering to the Nefesh distinctly as the part of a person is the feminine used.

Comment: OK but how could someone argue with mishna berachos 44a where the nusach is clearly quoted with a nun ?

Comment: @Frank, maybe they hold by a [different version](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=116&hilite=) that leaves out the last word altogether.